# Laptop screen keeps switching off

Tags: windows, laptop-display

Laptop screen keeps switching off, so I have plugged in a monitor which has been working fine.  I tried to start the laptop screen which I did yesterday but somehow I think I have made the laptop screen the primary screen but it’s all black.

I can bring the curser back onto the monitor no problem but the monitor only has the windows picture on. Nothing else at all to click on to.  I have tried F8 but it just opens up on the blank, black screen.

Comment: What laptop are you talking about? When does this happen?

Comment: Is the laptop screen completely off, or can you make out anything on it under strong illumination? It's possible the backlight might just be failing.  You can try plugging up an external keyboard+mouse and shutting the lid, which should disable that screen so at least you can function in the short term.

Answer (score 1):

If its Windows 7, hold down the windows logo key and press P, each time you do this it will scroll through the display options.